# Is it possible to create something like a MethodCallExpression without knowing the types of the related expressions?

Tags: c#, linq, expression-trees, roslyn

I am playing with the Roslyn CTP nuget package and thought I would acquainted with the `SyntaxVisitor<>` class so I am creating a `Roslyn.Compilers.CSharp.SyntaxNode` to `System.Linq.Expression` converter (which appears to work for any code that doesn't involve semantic knowledge unknown to the AST or provided outside of the visit call).

Anyway, I have the following code:

```
public override Expression VisitInvocationExpression(InvocationExpressionSyntax node) {
    ???
}
```

And I've got nothing. `node` has an `Expression` property which can be resolved by visiting it as long as it isn't a method call:

```
return Expression.Invoke(
    Visit(node.Expression), 
    node.ArgumentList.Arguments.Select(a => Visit(a.Expression))
)
```

This seems to work as long as `Expression` is not a method call. If it is a method call though (static, instance or extension), the first Visit winds up calling `VisitMemberAccessExpression` where I then fail (due to the nature of these not being members).

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Expression.Call` is the way to go. 
But still you would need to use semantic data to get associated reflection data such as Types and MethodInfo.

The way to go about it is:

1. Get compilation object by calling `Compilation.Create(...)` in other words: compile your program using Roslyn API
2. Get `SemanticModel` out of it by calling `GetSemanticModel(ast)`
3. Get TypeInfo calling GetTypeInfo(expression)

So... to sum it up

```
Compilation.Create(...).GetSemanticModel(ast).GetTypeInfo(expression);
```